# Dart function no returning the expected value

Tags: flutter, dart

I have created a function that receives a String date and returns a string that shows the time between the given date and the current DateTime in the format: x days ago, x months ago, just now, x years ago, yesterday, etc:

This is the code for that function:

```
 String tiempoDesdeFecha(String dateString, {bool numericDates = true}) {
      DateTime date = DateTime.parse(dateString);
      final date2 = DateTime.now();
      final difference = date2.difference(date);

      if ((difference.inDays / 365).floor() >= 2) {
        return "hace".tr()+'${(difference.inDays / 365).floor()}'+"yearsago".tr();
      } else if ((difference.inDays / 365).floor() >= 1  ) {
        return (numericDates) ? '1yearago'.tr() : 'lastyear'.tr()+" "+(numericDates).toString();
      } else if ((difference.inDays / 30).floor() >= 2) {
        return "hace".tr()+'${(difference.inDays / 365).floor()}'+"monthsago".tr();
      } else if ((difference.inDays / 30).floor() >= 1) {
        return (numericDates) ? '1monthago'.tr() : 'lastmonth'.tr();
      } else if ((difference.inDays / 7).floor() >= 2) {
        return "hace".tr()+'${(difference.inDays / 7).floor()}'+ 'weeksago'.tr();
      } else if ((difference.inDays / 7).floor() >= 1) {
        return (numericDates) ? "1weekago".tr() : 'lastweek'.tr();
      } else if (difference.inDays >= 2) {
        return "hace".tr()+'${difference.inDays}'+ 'daysago'.tr();
      } else if (difference.inDays >= 1) {
        return (numericDates) ? '1dayago'.tr() : 'yesterday'.tr();
      } else if (difference.inHours >= 2) {
        return "hace".tr()+'${difference.inHours}'+ 'hoursago'.tr();
      } else if (difference.inHours >= 1) {
        return (numericDates) ? '1hourago'.tr() : 'anhourago'.tr();
      } else if (difference.inMinutes >= 2) {
        return "hace".tr()+'${difference.inMinutes} ' +'minutesago'.tr();
      } else if (difference.inMinutes >= 1) {
        return (numericDates) ? '1minuteago'.tr() : 'aminuteago'.tr();
      } else if (difference.inSeconds >= 3) {
        return "hace".tr()+'${difference.inSeconds}'+ 'secondsago'.tr();
      } else {
        return 'justnow'.tr();
      }
    }
```

I have included the code to show the returned string in one of the four Locale I am using.

Everything is working fine, but the condition:

```
else if ((difference.inDays / 30).floor() >= 2) {
        return "hace".tr()+'${(difference.inDays / 365).floor()}'+"monthsago".tr();
```

which is always returning `0 months ago`.

I am calling the function from:

```
fecha_recibida = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm',"en").format(date);
fecha_recibida = tiempoDesdeFecha(fecha_recibida);
```

I am testing that issue with following String date:
"2021-5-5 19:34"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The body for that condition prints `difference.inDays / 365` instead of `difference.inDays / 30`, so it prints the number of years.  Also, FYI, you can use [truncating integer division](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/num/operator_truncate_divide.html) (`~/`) and avoid the need to call `floor()` all the time.

Comment: @jamesdlin, you are right, it works as you propose, please put your proposal as answer to my question.

Comment: Alt, you can also make use of https://pub.dev/packages/timeago

Comment: I commented instead of posting an answer because this problem was caused by a typo and  therefore should be closed.  It won't be generally useful to other people.

Comment: @jamesdlin, it was not really  a typo, but  I understand your point of view. I would have accepted your proposal as the right answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the error is in the returned string,

`difference.inDays / 365` must be `difference.inDays / 30`.

So the condition should look like..

```dart
else if ((difference.inDays / 30).floor() >= 2) {
        return "hace".tr()+'${(difference.inDays / 30).floor()}'+"monthsago".tr();
```

A plus, as @aman mentioned, you could use [timeago package](https://pub.dev/packages/timeago)